# Maximum number of h-dimensional hyper-edges without forming any (h+1) complete subgraph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings, combinatorial-optimization, hypergraph

This is about graph theory.

Define an h-dimensional hyperedge as a set that contains h vertices.

A graph of (h+1) vertices is h-complete if any h combination (or any subset with size h) is an h-dimensional hyperedge of this graph.

The question is: Suppose we have k vertices (points), what is the maximum number of h-dimensional hyperedge we can get without forming an h-complete subgraph?

Comment: For the complement hypergraph, every subset of size $h+1$ must contain an edge, and the minimal number of edges with this property is called Turan number $T(k,h+1,h)$. It is a subject of intensive study. See the survey by Sidorenko https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01929486

Comment: Thank you, @FedorPetrov. Very helpful and I believe this is the best I can get :).

Comment: TanGan, you seem to be off by 1 dimension wise.